# answering machine app on Galaxy Note

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s, auto-answer

I want to install an answering machine app on Galaxy Note, didn't find anything interesting in Google. What do you recommend? Or is there such a feature on the phone itself, in settings or somewhere?

Something with a recorded message saying "I'm not available now, please leave your message or phone number".

Comment: I found two questions quite similar to mine asked, but they didn't get any satisfying answers.

Comment: What's wrong with using your carrier's answering service?

Comment: Are you looking for voicemail providers? Like youmail or google voice? Or something different?

Comment: @Chahk: It doesn't have any.

Comment: @AlexB: If those two do what I want, then it'd be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Voice should do what you want if you're in the US.  On my phone I can go to `Settings -> Call settings -> Voicemail` and set it as the "Voicemail service" (you'll need the Google Voice app to do this).

There might be other apps to hook into this voicemail service setting but I can't find any at the moment.